# Expanding commit history in gitk

Tags: git, bash

I have a Windows 7 machine with Git Bash installed on it. I am fairly satisfied, but I wish to see the commit history in a nicer way. I have tried

```
log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

but I find a bit difficult to read it. Alternatively, I used gitk that shows the commit history in a nice way, but the window that display the graph is way too small. I googled for finding some alternatives, like gitg or gitx but they don't seem to work with git bash - at least in my understanding.

Is there any way to expand the gitk window to show the commits graph, or can you suggest me some other solution? If possible, I wish to stick to Git Bash.

Comment: When you say "way too small", do you mean that the _part of_ the window that shows the commit graph is too small relative to the rest of the window, the _content of_ the entire window is too small, e.g. the font needs to be increased, or the _entire window_ is too small?

Comment: Sorry for haven't been clear. I mean that it is  too small relative to the rest of the window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The handle for resizing that part of the `gitk` window isn't where you might expect it. Try dragging on the part that I've highlighted red here:

[image: gitk drag handle]

That should let you resize the part of the window containing the commit graph.